# Lighthouse in GitLab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, google-chrome-headless, lighthouse

I'm trying to use Lighthouse in GitLab CI to run a scan against a remote website after a deploy. The job keeps throwing an error.

My job configuration looks like this:

```
lighthouse:
  stage: scan
  image: markhobson/node-chrome
  script:
    - npm install -g lighthouse lighthouse-plugin-field-performance --unsafe-perm
    - lighthouse $URL --plugins=lighthouse-plugin-field-performance --chrome-flags=”--headless --no-sandbox” --verbose
```

I've also tried with `image: buildkite/puppeteer`. In both instances I get a similar error when I try to invoke Lighthouse, which looks like this:

```
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:22:42 GMT ChromeLauncher:verbose created /tmp/lighthouse.KXhqWF0
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:22:42 GMT ChromeLauncher:verbose Launching with command:
"/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable" --disable-translate --disable-extensions --disable-background-networking --disable-sync --metrics-recording-only --disable-default-apps --mute-audio --no-first-run --remote-debugging-port=44495 --disable-setuid-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/lighthouse.KXhqWF0 about:blank
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:22:42 GMT ChromeLauncher:verbose Chrome running with pid 36 on port 44495.
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:22:42 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:22:42 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:22:43 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:22:43 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:22:44 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.........
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:22:44 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...........
```

etc

```
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:23:07 GMT ChromeLauncher:error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:44495
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:23:07 GMT ChromeLauncher:error Logging contents of /tmp/lighthouse.KXhqWF0/chrome-err.log
Wed, 09 Oct 2019 20:23:07 GMT ChromeLauncher:error 
(google-chrome-stable:36): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
[1009/202244.656645:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly

Unable to connect to Chrome
```

I'm not entirely sure what I need to do at this point. I'm questioning whether or not to try a more basic node image and try installing what I need manually, which I tried originally and found that managing Chrome/Chromium with Lighthouse was not quite as straight-forward as I wanted. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using this image which has both everything installed ready to execute a report https://hub.docker.com/r/femtopixel/google-lighthouse/